# What causes: "Notice: Uninitialized string offset" to appear?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that users fill out, and on the form there are multiple identical fields, like "project name", "project date", "catagory", etc. Based on how many forms a user is submitting, my goal is to:

1. loop over the number of forms
2. create individual SQL insert statements

However, PHP throws me a NOTICE that I don't seem to understand:

**Notice:**

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 ...dataPasser.php on line 90

**PHP**

```
$myQuery = array();

if ($varsCount != 0)
{
  for ($i=0; $i <= $varsCount; $i++)
  {
    $var = "insert into projectData values ('" . $catagory[$i] . "', '" .  $task[$i] . "', '" . $fullText[$i] . "', '" . $dueDate[$i] . "', null, '" . $empId[$i] ."')";
    array_push($myQuery, $var);     
  }
}
```

There are references to this issue I am having, but they are not exact and I am having trouble deducing where the actual problem stems from. I would greatly appreciate any help in understanding what is causing the array to not initialize properly.

Comment: You leave a lot out of the example, but what's the output of var_dump($myQuery)?

Comment: Where is line 90, and what is the full notice?

Comment: I just wanted to add that you don't need to use array_push here at all. Just do this. $myQuery[] = $var;

Comment: This question is closed but maybe I can help anyone who like me once in a while gets this error due to forgetting to include curly braces when invoking a class property dynamically which is an array (or implements ArrayAccess) while at the same accessing one of its elements.  E.g. `$this->$arrayMember[$index]` will evaluate `$arrayMember[$index]` first; so explicitly denote the dynamic member name portion like this: `$this->{$arrayMember}[$index]`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This error would occur if any of the following variables were actually strings or null instead of arrays, in which case accessing them with an array syntax `$var[$i]` would be like trying to access a specific character in a string:

```
$catagory
$task
$fullText
$dueDate
$empId
```

In short, everything in your insert query.

Perhaps the `$catagory` variable is misspelled?

Comment: man, i just want to kick myself in the head. OF COURSE! There is only 1 unique $empId. I was focused on the $myQuery array that I didn't pay attention to the others. Thanks so much! I changed $empID[$i] to $empId and the Notice disappeared as $empId is NOT an array.

Comment: I think part of the confusion here is that when indexing `$var[$i]` it could be either a string or an array...

Comment: +1 For Perfect Ans (Y) ... !

Answer (score 15):

It means one of your arrays isn't actually an array.

By the way, your if check is unnecessary. If $varsCount is 0 the for loop won't execute anyway.

Comment: yea, I've seen this comment before. Unfortunately, I'm not understanding how its not an array? I'm outputting the data into FirePHP and I see it via the POST and then in the variables as well.

Comment: ok thanks, I only posted a portion of the code to make it easy to read. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

The error may occur when the number of times you iterate the array is greater than the actual size of the array. for example:

```
 $one="909";
 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    echo ' '.$one[$i];
```

will show the error.
  first case u can take the mod of i.. for example

```
function mod($i,$length){
  $m = $i % $size;
  if ($m > $size)
  mod($m,$size)
  return $m;
}

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
  $k=mod($i,3);
  echo ' '.$one[$k];
}
```

or might be it not an array (maybe it was a value and you tried to access it like an array)
  for example:

```
$k = 2;
$k[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to test and initialize your arrays before you use them :

```
if( !isset($catagory[$i]) ) $catagory[$i] = '' ;
if( !isset($task[$i]) ) $task[$i] = '' ;
if( !isset($fullText[$i]) ) $fullText[$i] = '' ;
if( !isset($dueDate[$i]) ) $dueDate[$i] = '' ;
if( !isset($empId[$i]) ) $empId[$i] = '' ;
```

If `$catagory[$i]` doesn't exist, you create (Uninitialized) one ... that's all ;
=> PHP try to read on your table in the address `$i`, but at this address, there's nothing, this address doesn't exist => PHP return you a notice, and it put nothing to you string.
So you code is not very clean, it takes you some resources that down you server's performance (just a very little).

Take care about your MySQL tables default values

```
if( !isset($dueDate[$i]) ) $dueDate[$i] = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ;
```

or

```
if( !isset($dueDate[$i]) ) $dueDate[$i] = 'NULL' ;
```

Comment: right, but what if its supposed to be an array, `if(!isset($myarray[$i])) $myarray[$i]=array();` perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the contents of your array with

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $arr, TRUE ) . '</pre>';
```