# Uninitialized string offset: 0 error in Facebook FBML Application

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

I have created app. in FBML on facebook plateform in past. This app. is working fine till last week but now it shows error as

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.net/httpdocs/new/client/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php on line 310
```

and keeps refreshing on it. Why this is happening. Please help. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats just a notice not an error.

Probably php configuration has changed so that it prints out notice level "errors".

If thats 3rd party code, then just comment out a line in php.ini that starts with `error_reporting` (so that it doesn't notify you about notices) or in your php script execute this:

```
// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

If thats your code then read: [What causes: "Notice: Uninitialized string offset" to appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263636/php-what-causes-notice-uninitialized-string-offset-to-appear)

You are welcome to read more about [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).