# Uninitialized string offset while building array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am getting the following error from the method presented below:

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 5 in /path/to/file.php on line 30 Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in path/to/file.php on line 30

```
private function parse($xml, $index = '') {
    echo count($xml->children()); //outputs 6
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($xml->children() as $key => $value) {

        $this->$key[$count] = array();
        $count++;

    }

}
```

**Any ideas why if I build an multi-dimensional in this way it results in an error?**

If I change the assignment to:

```
$this->$key = array($count = > array());
```

This simply re-assigns the property each loop.
Thanks
Rich

Comment: Can you add the XML you are dealing with so that we can have a better picture ??

Comment: possible duplicate: [PHP: What causes: “Notice: Uninitialized string offset” to appear?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263636/php-what-causes-notice-uninitialized-string-offset-to-appear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you've got a string:

```
$string = 'abc`;
```

Doing substring access (which looks like array) will return you the character:

```
echo $string[2]; # c
```

Or you get your error when you're out of the index:

```
echo $string[3]; # null + warning
```

So now accessing a member of your object `$this` dynamically:

```
$this->$string[2]; # access $this->c
```

However this one breaks hardly:

```
$this->$string[3]; # access $this->null (not possible)
```

This gives you your fatal error of an empty property, a property with no name.

This explain what happens in your code, you have not told what you're trying to do so I hope this information will help you to continue with writing your parse function.

Comment: I see. So I am accessing a piece of the string, or trying to reassign a part of a string instead of assigning a new index.

Comment: You are actually first of all dynamically saying the name of the property. As the property results in no-name, you get the fatal error.

Comment: I am trying to dynamically build a multi-dimensional array. The xml has a handful of nodes named 'Class', which I'd like to set as an array $this->class[0], $this->class[1]... which has sub arrays. I want it dynamic because I have a few similarly structured XML files which I don't want to know all the names of each node. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to create the array before filling it.
I.e. `$this->key = array();`

That is, before looping through the XML elements.