# Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1

Tags: php

i have problem in this code on line 66
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 on line 66

```
<?php
echo cologne_phon("d");
echo "<br />";
echo cologne_phon("ch dc");
echo "<br />";
echo cologne_phon("dc"); 

function cologne_phon($word){

    /**
     * @param  string  $word string to be analyzed
     * @return string  $value represents the K?lner Phonetik value
     * @access public
     */

    //prepare for processing
    $word=strtolower($word);
    $substitution=array(
                        "?"=>"a",
                        "?"=>"o",
                        "ü"=>"u",
                        "?"=>"ss",
                        "ph"=>"f"
                        );

    foreach ($substitution as $letter=>$substitution) {
        $word=str_replace($letter,$substitution,$word);
    }

    $len=strlen($word);

    //Rule for exeptions
    $exceptionsLeading=array(
                             4=>array("ca","ch","ck","cl","co","cq","cu","cx"),
                             8=>array("dc","ds","dz","tc","ts","tz")
                             );

    $exceptionsFollowing=array("sc","zc","cx","kx","qx");

    //Table for coding
    $codingTable=array(
                       0=>array("a","e","i","j","o","u","y"),
                       1=>array("b","p"),
                       2=>array("d","t"),
                       3=>array("f","v","w"),
                       4=>array("c","g","k","q"),
                       48=>array("x"),
                       5=>array("l"),
                       6=>array("m","n"),
                       7=>array("r"),
                       8=>array("c","s","z"),
                       );

    for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
        $value[$i]='';

        //Exceptions
        if ($i==0 && $word[$i]=='cr') 
            $value[$i]=4;

        foreach ($exceptionsLeading as $code =>$letters) {
            if (in_array($word[$i].$word[$i+1],$letters)){
                $value[$i]=$code;
            }
        }

        if ($i!=0 && (in_array($word[$i-1].$word[$i], 
                               $exceptionsFollowing))) {
            $value[$i]=8;        
        }                

        //Normal encoding
        if ($value[$i]==""){
            foreach ($codingTable as $code=>$letters) {
                if (in_array($word[$i],$letters))$value[$i]=$code;
            }
        }
    }

    //delete double values
    $len=count($value);

    for ($i=1;$i<$len;$i++){
        if ($value[$i]==$value[$i-1]) $value[$i]="";
    }

    //delete vocals 
    for ($i=1;$i>$len;$i++){//omitting first characer code and h
        if ($value[$i]==0) $value[$i]="";
    }

    var_dump($value);
    $value=array_filter($value);
    $value=implode('',$value);

    return $value;
}
```

i try a lot of way for fix but nothing work with me so need help please
original code here in php site
http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php#84881

Comment: Which line is getting the error?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: `I try a lot of way for fix` - but have you tied to understand what this message means first? [What causes: "Notice: Uninitialized string offset" to appear?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1263636/1235698)

Comment: @Barmar line 66

Comment: @Barmar  problem not in space

Comment: Nobody is counting lines for you. And it is insulting to dump all that non formatted  code.

Comment: Looks like a few problems. Start by adding `- 1` in `for($i = 0; $i < $len - 1; $i++) {` below "Table for coding". It'll still be an issue when $len = 1, but that might get you on the right track.

Comment: @AOWulinGuide The problem isn't in the spacing, it just makes it hard for us to read and understand.

Comment: @Eggsalad That's not right, because there's other code in the loop that needs to process the last character of the string. See my answer for the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
        if (in_array($word[$i].$word[$i+1],$letters)){
```

On the last iteration of the loop, `$word[$i]` is the last character of `$word`, and there is no `$word[$i+1]`. You should change this to check that you're not at the end of the string:

```
        if ($i < $len - 1 && in_array($word[$i].$word[$i+1],$letters)){
```