# Why does this function generate an uninitialized string offset notice?

Tags: php

I'm having this error when I run my program:

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\str_rev.php on line 21

What causes that?

```
<?php

    //strrev($arg);
    /*$str = "ademola";
    echo strrev("$str");
    */

    function reverse_String($str){
        $i = 0;
        while(!empty($str[$i])){
            echo $str[$i];
                $i++;
        }


        for($r = $i; $r > -1; $r--){
            $reverse = $str[$r];
            echo $reverse;

        }
    }

    reverse_String("Ademola");
?>
```

Output:

> Ademola
>   `Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\str_rev.php on line 21`
>   alomedA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes: "Notice: Uninitialized string offset" to appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263636/what-causes-notice-uninitialized-string-offset-to-appear)

Comment: @Chris while it's the same underlying issue, that question is different and its answers are lacking in anything relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The `$i++;` in your first `while` loop increments `$i` to 7 in its last iteration. The condition `!empty($str[$i])` is no longer satisfied, so the loop does not execute again, but `$i` is still 7 when the next loop starts, which is an index beyond the end of the string.

There are various ways to fix this, a simple way is to subtract 1 from the counter when you define your second loop to set `$r` to the index of the last character in the string.

```
for($r = $i - 1; $r > -1; $r--){ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Don't Panic there are many ways to fix this,
you can use isset as:-

```
    for($r = $i; $r > -1; $r--){
        if(isset($str[$r])) {
            $reverse = $str[$r];
            echo $reverse;
        }
    }
```

Or to reverse the string you can simply use the php's built in function ([strrev](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php))

```
echo strrev('Ademola')
```