# Symfony Doctrine "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0"

Tags: symfony, doctrine, any

I'm getting an unexplainable-to-me "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0" error.   Any help appreciated.   Details below:

Manual query of database (works - 1635 is just one example):

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT(loc) FROM `post` WHERE author = ANY ( SELECT DISTINCT(author) FROM `post` WHERE loc=1635 );
```

Repository in Symfony --  query results in "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0"

---

```
    $qb2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
      ->select('DISTINCT (p.loc)')
      ->Where('DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),  :timePer, \'day\') < p.publishedAt')
      ->andWhere('p.author = ANY ( SELECT DISTINCT(p.author) FROM \`post\` WHERE p.loc = :ccc )')
      ->setParameter('timePer', $timePeriodDays)
      ->setParameter('ccc', $passed_ccc)
      ->getQuery();


    $lResult =  $qb2->execute();
    return $lResult;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1263654/608170

Answer (score 0):

The logic doesn't seem to be the same in your dql query and the plain sql one. The dql query (without the time part) would translate into following plain sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.loc) FROM `post` p WHERE p.author = ANY ( SELECT DISTINCT(p.author) FROM `post` p1 WHERE p.loc=1635 );
```

Additionally the query builder is mixing dql and sql which doesn't work (in using table name instead of entity name to be more specific). You can try with the below updated version (replace "YourBundle:Post" with your actual bundle:entity names):

```
$qb2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('DISTINCT (p.loc)')
    ->Where('DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),  :timePer, \'day\') < p.publishedAt')
    ->andWhere('p.author = ANY ( SELECT DISTINCT(p1.author) FROM YourBundle:Post p1 WHERE p1.loc = :ccc )')
    ->setParameter('timePer', $timePeriodDays)
    ->setParameter('ccc', $passed_ccc)
    ->getQuery();

$lResult =  $qb2->execute();
return $lResult;
```

as a side-note, if you still hit the same error as originally with this, can you please dump out the parameters that you are using in this query.