# Warning: Uninitialized string offset 0 in

Tags: php, php-8.2

Warning: Uninitialized string offset 0 in

I have this error on the line (`if($subMenues[$j]['id'] == $permisosMod[$k]['id_sub_menus']){`);

```
public function Setupdashboard(){
            $data['page_tag']       = "Configuración - Empresa*";
            $data['page_title']     = "Configuración - Empresa*";
            $data['page_name']      = "setupdashboard";
            $data['permisos']       = $_SESSION['permisos'];
            $data['permisosMod']    = $_SESSION['permisosMod'];
            $data['ThisModulo']     = getModulo(get_class($this));  
            $_SESSION['moduloFull'] = $this->model->selectModulo($data['ThisModulo']);
            $data['menues']         = $this->model->selectMenues($data['ThisModulo']);
            for ($i=0; $i < count($data['menues']); $i++) { 
                $subMenues = $data['menues'][$i]['subMenues'];
                for ($j=0; $j < count((array)$subMenues); $j++) {
                    $permisosMod = $data['permisosMod'];
                    for ($k=0; $k < count($permisosMod); $k++) { 
                        if($subMenues[$j]['id'] == $permisosMod[$k]['id_sub_menus']){
                            $data['menues'][$i]['subMenues'][$j]['r'] = $permisosMod[$k]['r'];
                            $data['menues'][$i]['subMenues'][$j]['w'] = $permisosMod[$k]['w'];
                            $data['menues'][$i]['subMenues'][$j]['u'] = $permisosMod[$k]['u'];
                            $data['menues'][$i]['subMenues'][$j]['d'] = $permisosMod[$k]['d'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $data['nav_bar']        = "nav_admin.php";
            $data['page_functions_js']  = "functions_dsetupsdashboard.js";
            $this->views->getView($this,"setupdashboard",$data);
        }
```

After this error, I have another result of this and I say this because before installing php 8 it worked correctly for me.

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\ebsoftap\Controllers\Setupdashboard.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ebsoftap\Libraries\Core\Load.php(12): Setupdashboard->Setupdashboard('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ebsoftap\Index.php(33): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes: "Notice: Uninitialized string offset" to appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263636/what-causes-notice-uninitialized-string-offset-to-appear)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my code is in this line: `for ($j=0; $j < count((array)$subMenues); $j++) {`, and previously I had it this way and it still failed in php 8.2  `for ($j=0; $j < count($subMenues); $j++) {`

To fix this, I added a check before the for loop to make sure that $subMenues is a valid array.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data['menues']); $i++) { 
    $subMenues = $data['menues'][$i]['subMenues'];
    if (is_array($subMenues)) { // Verificar si $subMenues es un array válido
        for ($j=0; $j < count($subMenues); $j++) {
            // Resto del código
        }
    }
}
```